# problems with adding Child node to existing XML elements

Tags: apex, string, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse html in apex class using XML Parser Document and XML Nodes classes.
At one point I need to add another xml which is present as string with me to one of the nodes as child node in my XML.

Whenever I use addChildElement()  method , it appends the entire string as child element of my node. How do I add it correctly , so the new xml string is added as XML nodes instead of string.

Comment: HTML is SGML not XML; "well formed" HTML is often not well formed XML. Expect XML-based parsing to fail unless you are actually processing XHTML. You need to parse the "insert markup" as well, so you have XML Nodes to insert, or you need to drop the idea of actual parsing and apply some string manipulation instead.